Rewrites under the guise of editing questions must be banned
I only asked two questions, and both were essentially rewritten:

What is this weapon used in The Peacemaker?
Babylon - name all movies used in the concluding 30 seconds

This must not be permitted. I understand fixing typos and adding punctuation, but not practically rewriting another person's thoughts, dreams, and desires. Most of us are from free-speech cultures. This is not Mao Zedong's China. You don't know me. Your view of how my questions should be asked is irrelevant. Ask your own if you know better.

Can you explain what about the edits constituted a "rewrite" of your "thoughts, dreams, and desires"? To me, they look like basic grammar improvements that don't change the questions in any meaningful way. I don't see anything objectionable about them at all.

Your question “Babylon - name all movies used in the concluding 30 seconds” was not rewritten. The edits are pretty minor and add clarity and improve the question. Is that one of the questions you’re concerned about? If so, can you clarify your concern? Also, you can revert edits if you don’t like them.

@ToddWilcox For transparency's sake, they did roll back the edit to their first question, so I re-applied it on the basis that it was an objective improvement and OP had (at the time) offered no explanation as to why they rolled it back.

I'd take it as a compliment. People found your questions sufficiently interesting as to devote the time and energy to improving them, allowing even more people to enjoy them.

Editing a question (or answer) isn't just allowed on SE sites, it's explicitly encouraged. It's one of the key things that distinguishes us from, for example, Quora or Yahoo Answers.

Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?
Other people can edit my posts?!
All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons and this site is
collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that
needs improvement, click edit and help us make it so!
All edits are tracked in a public revision history. To view revisions,
click the edit date on the post.
If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being
collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the
site for you.


In the case of your two questions, both sets of edits significantly increased the clarity and readability, removing an incorrect timestamp, correcting an incorrect name and adding grammatical flair to make it easier to read.
What is this weapon used in The Peacemaker? (Revisions)


Babylon - name all movies used in the concluding 30 seconds (Revisions)


